# Ошибка NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method getApplicationInfo() on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, activity

Пытаюсь отобразить данные с БД в активити, делал ровно по учебнику, но как бы ни пытался разобраться, выходит постоянно одна и та же ошибка:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo().

Не понимаю в чём проблема, т.к. не совсем ещё знаком со всеми тонкостями.

**MainActivity:**

```java
package com.example.hr4;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    Button btnShowDB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DBbt); // <= строка 21
    ListView listDB = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.DBlist);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    ...
}
```

**Трассировка стека:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hr4, PID: 5909
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hr4/com.example.hr4.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:148)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:99)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:436)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:852)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:819)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:640)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:261)
        at com.example.hr4.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:21)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `findViewById` внутри `onCreate`

Comment: Тогда область видимости будет только в методе onCreate, а у меня переменная listDB исп-тся в обработчике событий DBLoadBt

Comment: Переменную оставьте там, но инициализацию перенесите в onCreate

Comment: та же самая ошибка возникает. И в трассировке стека на неё же указывает (at com.example.hr4.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:21)), если вы об этом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методом `findViewById` можно пользоваться только после того, как вы задали xml-разметку с помощью метода `setContentView`. До вызова метода `setContentView` фреймворк Андроид не может знать о том, какие view у вас есть в xml-разметке.

Поэтому, чтобы избежать RuntimeException, вам нужно перенести вызов `findViewById` в метод `onCreate` после вызова `setContentView`:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
    }

}
```